# Timeout on codeblocks :Program to reverse a String (Eg- ab cd will be reversed to ba dc)

Tags: string, timeout, codeblocks

Here is a [link](http://codepad.org/CjR111s4) to the program which is giving the error Timeout

The same program :

```
void reverse(char a[],int slen, int elen)
 {
     int start,end,temp;
     for(start=slen,end=elen;start<end;start++,end--)
            {
                temp=a[start];
                a[start]=a[end];
                a[end]=temp;
            }
 }

 void reverseall(char a[])
  {
      int i,n=0,len=0;
      for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        while(a[i]!='\0')
            n++;
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           while(a[i]!= ' ')
                len++;
           reverse(a,i-len,i-1);
       }
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i];
  }
int main()
 {
     char a[20]="hi how are you";
     reverseall(a);
     return 0;
 }
```

What could be the reason?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your while loops incrementing n and len are checking that a[i] is '\0' or ' ' without changing i in the body of the loop.  They should be checking if a[n] or a[len] is what you want, since n and len are the values being incremented in the loop.

Comment: Since the terms of the condition that end each loop are not changed inside the loops, they both will run forever.

Comment: I made the changes but still getting the same error. I worked it out on the paper, cant seem to find the mistake :(  http://codepad.org/BcLHQBxC --- link to the new program

Comment: your while loop while(a[j]!= ' ' || a[j]!='\0') will never exit, because one of those two conditions will ALWAYS be true... they could only both be false if both a[j]=' ' and a[j]='\0'